# How to limit the direction of resize of a container with mouse

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container which can resize from `right-side` and `bottom` .

It is resizing correctly but in both sides that is in `height` and `width` at the same time in unlimited length .

Can there be a way to limit direction of resize either bottom side or right side increase or decrease in size .

Single side increase is only possible when using 1 condition in `if`

Here is the code :

```js
const panel = document.getElementById("styleChangeOuterTag");
let m_pos;
let m_pos1;

function resize(e) {
  const dx = m_pos - e.x;
  const dy = m_pos1 - e.y;
  m_pos = e.x;
  m_pos1 = e.y;
  panel.style.width = (parseInt(getComputedStyle(panel).width) - dx) + "px";
  panel.style.height = (parseInt(getComputedStyle(panel).height) - dy) + "px";
}

panel.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
  if (e.offsetX > panel.clientWidth - 10) {
    m_pos = e.x;
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", resize);
  } else if (e.offsetY > panel.clientHeight - 10) {
    m_pos1 = e.y;
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", resize);
  }
});

document.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
  document.removeEventListener("mousemove", resize);
});
```

```css
#styleChangeOuterTag {
  /* display: none; */
  /* position: fixed; */
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 2vw 1.5vw;
  background-color: rgb(255, 245, 245);
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 60, 255);
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 5;
  user-select: none;
}

#styleChangeOuterTag::after {
  content: '';
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: ew-resize;
}

#styleChangeOuterTag::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  cursor: ns-resize;
}

#styleOptionDetails {
  border: 2px solid purple;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 1vw;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="styleChangeOuterTag">
  <hr>
  <div id="styleOptionDetails">
  </div>
</div>
```

> Can you tell about how to size the clickable width(grey part in Container-which trigger resize) as now it not right in size and don't work in whole width
>
> > **created with e.offsetX > panel.clientWidth - 10**

**Thanks for help in advance**

Comment: Have you tried adding a `max-height` and `max-width` to the resizable container in the CSS?

Comment: It worked fine @Sarah thanks for that . Can you tell about resize in single direction

Comment: You can set `min-height` and `min-width` also to only allow it to get so small.

Comment: Yes that was just missed from my mind . It is easy and reliable than any other `JS` solution @Sarah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add additional condition in to your `resize` function, something like this:

```js
const minWidth = 150
const maxWidth = 500
const minHeight = 150
const maxHeight = 500

function resize(e) {
  const dx = m_pos - e.x;
  const dy = m_pos1 - e.y;
  m_pos = e.x;
  m_pos1 = e.y;

  const newWidth = parseInt(getComputedStyle(panel).width) - dx
  const newHeight = parseInt(getComputedStyle(panel).height - dy

  if (newWidth > minWidth && newWidth < maxWidth) {
    panel.style.width = newWidth + "px";
  }
  if (newHeight > minHeight && newHeight < maxHeight) {
    panel.style.height = newHeight + "px";
  }
}
```

Comment: Can it be possible to increase size in one direction only at time

Comment: You can add 2 additional html elements which will positioned over your `panel`, and which will handle mouse events, one for resize width and second for resize height. And split your `resize` function to `resizeX` and `resizeY`. Most of other code will be the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kuzzy , It means it is not possible with single function am I right or there any other way round

Comment: Can you tell about how to size the clickable width(grey part in Container) as now it not right in size and don't work in whole width

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand question correct, but you can change width of gray bars in css:  `#styleChangeOuterTag::after { width: yourNewWidth }` for right bar and `#styleChangeOuterTag::before { height: yourNewHeight }` for bottom. And modify conditions in JS `e.offsetX > panel.clientWidth - yourNewWidth` and `e.offsetY > panel.clientHeight - yourNewHeight`.

Comment: About other question, everything is possible, but it may be more complicated solutions. You can, for example, detect in what part of your panel mousedown event was triggered (right or bottom) and decide which part of your function to apply (change only width or only height).